# showing values from bigger to smaller scaterplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec), color = 'red') +
    geom_text(aes(wt, mpg, label=cyl)) + 
    geom_text_repel(aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

If you run this code, you will get a plot that looks like this: 
[image]
What I'm interested in doing is change the order of the `qseq`. Meaning, the `biggest` qsec will be assigned the `smaller` circle, while the smallest qsec will be assigned the bigger one.

How can I do this?

Comment: maybe create a variable `df$qsecInv <- 1 / df$qsec` or something similar and use that.

Comment: @Imo that's a nice workaround, but how will I be able to display the legend correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding `scale_size(trans = "reverse")` solves your problem:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec), color = 'red') +
  geom_text(aes(wt, mpg, label=cyl)) + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)+
  scale_size(trans = "reverse")
```

I'm only adding a picture of the data to help others with this issue
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you sir!